# How Do I Make my Site Automatically Reload When I Change my HTML?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I write HTML, I have Google Chrome open on one side and VS Code on the other.  Then when I save, I go to Chrome and reload the page.  However, how do I make it so that when I save my code, the page automatically reloads in Chrome?

Comment: You can use [a live server](https://www.google.com/search?q=reloading+server+npm&oq=live+server+npm)

Answer (score 2):

Use a live server. One such option is the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) VS Code extension. You could also use the [`live-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) NPM package or the [`live-server`](https://pypi.org/project/live-server/) PyPI package.

There are plenty of options out there, just pick the best one for your needs.